# Options to run oracle forms and report (12c) without internet explorer

Tags: oracle, internet-explorer, oracle12c, java-web-start

I need Options to run oracle forms and report (12c) without internet explorer
except the Forms Standalone Launcher (FSAL) and Java Web Start (JWS)

many thanks

Comment: If you don't want to use IE then use Edge, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, etc. or even Lynx. There are many other web browsers but asking for a list of software is off-topic for StackOverflow. If you are after something else then you need to [edit] your question to clarify.

Comment: thank you for your replay,
what I need is a secure software to run the forms, I mean more than google chrome

Answer (score 0):

Oracle Forms 12c does support browsers other than Internet Explorer, so just use a different browser. For more info about the compatible browsers, see here: https://docs.oracle.com/en/middleware/developer-tools/forms/12.2.1.4/working-forms/deploying-applications.html#GUID-5E437DF1-5A75-4866-B9ED-9922C621B893

Comment: thank you for your replay, what I need is a secure software to run the forms, I mean more than google chrome and explorer

Comment: When i use the jws using jnlp the form redirect to start page not to the forms page home page that saw the oracle installed successfully and show the version of it